# Glitch of camera preview on MIUI (need help MIUI users/developers)

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, miui

I get a blink and an incorrect preview image of the camera (for more details see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46130293/glitch-camera-preview-on-the-users-device) question). I get similar reviews from MIUI (Android 5-7) users, but I do not have device with MIUI for testing. Thanks to the help of one user, I got a log from his device. But, unfortunately, I can not identify the exact cause of the failure.

Log (only the most important part)

```
10-02 16:08:50.632   583 11772 D QCameraParameters: int32_t qcamera::QCameraParameters::setNumOfSnapshot():   nBurstNum = 1, nExpnum = 1
10-02 16:08:50.632   583 11772 E QCamera2HWI: int qcamera::QCamera2HardwareInterface::commitParameterChanges(), mParameters.isMorphoHDREnabled() 0
10-02 16:08:50.632   583 11772 D QCameraMorphoPostProc: Enable++, enable 0
10-02 16:08:50.632   583 11772 E QCameraMorphoPostProc: Enable: nothing to changed!
10-02 16:08:50.632   583 11772 D QCameraMorphoPostProc: Enable++, enable 0
10-02 16:08:50.632   583 11772 E QCameraMorphoPostProc: Enable: nothing to changed!
10-02 16:08:50.632   583 11772 E QCamera2HWI: int qcamera::QCamera2HardwareInterface::commitParameterChanges(), mParameters.isMorphoHHTEnabled() 0
10-02 16:08:50.632   583 11772 D QCameraMorphoPostProc: Enable++, enable 0
10-02 16:08:50.632   583 11772 E QCameraMorphoPostProc: Enable: nothing to changed!
10-02 16:08:50.647   616 11789 E mm-camera: :cpp_hardware_set_clock:356 Set clock 160000000 BW abg 209952000 BW inst 209952000
10-02 16:08:50.648   616 11789 D mm-camera: cpp_hw_params_update_wnr_params:6505, invalid trigger input 0.000000
10-02 16:08:50.652 11692 11692 I Finsky  : [1] com.google.android.finsky.utils.ad.onTrimMemory(2): Memory trim requested to level 10
10-02 16:08:50.666   583 11832 I QCamera2HWI: [KPI Perf] static void qcamera::QCamera2HardwareInterface::preview_stream_cb_routine(mm_camera_super_buf_t*, qcamera::QCameraStream*, void*) : PROFILE_FIRST_PREVIEW_FRAME
10-02 16:08:50.670   616 11807 E mm-camera: iface_util_calc_cds_trigger:<cds_debug> HAL CDS mode on
10-02 16:08:50.670   616 11807 E mm-camera: iface_util_calc_cds_trigger:<cds_debug> take CDS! request enb = 1, curr enb = 0 curr_triiger 0.000000, lowlight_start 385.000000, lowlight_end 428.000000
10-02 16:08:50.672   616 11781 E mm-camera-isp2: bf_stats47_stats_config_update:2650 roi from 3a
10-02 16:08:50.673   616 11781 E mm-camera-isp2: bf_stats47_validate_roi_boundary:1732 error: invalid w 92 for x 934 y 422 h 92 Changed w 91
10-02 16:08:50.673   616 11781 E mm-camera-isp2: bf_stats47_validate_roi_boundary:1739 error: invalid h 92 for x 934 y 422 w 91 Changed h 91
10-02 16:08:50.673   616 11781 E mm-camera-isp2: bf_stats47_validate_roi_boundary:1711 error: invalid x 1027 for y 422 w 92 h 92 Changed x 1026
10-02 16:08:50.673   616 11781 E mm-camera-isp2: bf_stats47_validate_roi_boundary:1732 error: invalid w 92 for x 1026 y 422 h 92 Changed w 91
10-02 16:08:50.673   616 11781 E mm-camera-isp2: bf_stats47_validate_roi_boundary:1739 error: invalid h 92 for x 1026 y 422 w 91 Changed h 91
10-02 16:08:50.673   616 11781 E mm-camera-isp2: bf_stats47_validate_roi_boundary:1732 error: invalid w 92 for x 1120 y 422 h 92 Changed w 91
10-02 16:08:50.673   616 11781 E mm-camera-isp2: bf_stats47_validate_roi_boundary:1739 error: invalid h 92 for x 1120 y 422 w 91 Changed h 91
10-02 16:08:50.673   616 11781 E mm-camera-isp2: bf_stats47_validate_roi_boundary:1711 error: invalid x 1213 for y 422 w 92 h 92 Changed x 1212
10-02 16:08:50.673   616 11781 E mm-camera-isp2: bf_stats47_validate_roi_boundary:1732 error: invalid w 92 for x 1212 y 422 h 92 Changed w 91
10-02 16:08:50.673   616 11781 E mm-camera-isp2: bf_stats47_validate_roi_boundary:1739 error: invalid h 92 for x 1212 y 422 w 91 Changed h 91
10-02 16:08:50.673   616 11781 E mm-camera-isp2: bf_stats47_validate_roi_boundary:1732 error: invalid w 92 for x 1306 y 422 h 92 Changed w 91
10-02 16:08:50.673   616 11781 E mm-camera-isp2: bf_stats47_validate_roi_boundary:1739 error: invalid h 92 for x 1306 y 422 w 91 Changed h 91
10-02 16:08:50.673   616 11781 E mm-camera-isp2: bf_stats47_validate_roi_boundary:1725 error: invalid y 515 for x 934 w 92 h 92 Changed y 514
10-02 16:08:50.673   616 11781 E mm-camera-isp2: bf_stats47_validate_roi_boundary:1732 error: invalid w 92 for x 934 y 514 h 92 Changed w 91
10-02 16:08:50.673   616 11781 E mm-camera-isp2: bf_stats47_validate_roi_boundary:1739 error: invalid h 92 for x 934 y 514 w 91 Changed h 91
10-02 16:08:50.673   616 11781 E mm-camera-isp2: bf_stats47_validate_roi_boundary:1711 error: invalid x 1027 for y 515 w 92 h 92 Changed x 1026
10-02 16:08:50.673   616 11781 E mm-camera-isp2: bf_stats47_validate_roi_boundary:1725 error: invalid y 515 for x 1026 w 92 h 92 Changed y 514
10-02 16:08:50.673   616 11781 E mm-camera-isp2: bf_stats47_validate_roi_boundary:1732 error: invalid w 92 for x 1026 y 514 h 92 Changed w 91
10-02 16:08:50.673   616 11781 E mm-camera-isp2: bf_stats47_validate_roi_boundary:1739 error: invalid h 92 for x 1026 y 514 w 91 Changed h 91
10-02 16:08:50.673   616 11781 E mm-camera-isp2: bf_stats47_validate_roi_boundary:1725 error: invalid y 515 for x 1120 w 92 h 92 Changed y 514
10-02 16:08:50.673   616 11781 E mm-camera-isp2: bf_stats47_validate_roi_boundary:1732 error: invalid w 92 for x 1120 y 514 h 92 Changed w 91
10-02 16:08:50.673   616 11781 E mm-camera-isp2: bf_stats47_validate_roi_boundary:1739 error: invalid h 92 for x 1120 y 514 w 91 Changed h 91
10-02 16:08:50.673   616 11781 E mm-camera-isp2: bf_stats47_validate_roi_boundary:1711 error: invalid x 1213 for y 515 w 92 h 92 Changed x 1212
10-02 16:08:50.673   616 11781 E mm-camera-isp2: bf_stats47_validate_roi_boundary:1725 error: invalid y 515 for x 1212 w 92 h 92 Changed y 514
10-02 16:08:50.673   616 11781 E mm-camera-isp2: bf_stats47_validate_roi_boundary:1732 error: invalid w 92 for x 1212 y 514 h 92 Changed w 91
10-02 16:08:50.673   616 11781 E mm-camera-isp2: bf_stats47_validate_roi_boundary:1739 error: invalid h 92 for x 1212 y 514 w 91 Changed h 91
10-02 16:08:50.673   616 11781 E mm-camera-isp2: bf_stats47_validate_roi_boundary:1725 error: invalid y 515 for x 1306 w 92 h 92 Changed y 514
10-02 16:08:50.673   616 11781 E mm-camera-isp2: bf_stats47_validate_roi_boundary:1732 error: invalid w 92 for x 1306 y 514 h 92 Changed w 91
10-02 16:08:50.673   616 11781 E mm-camera-isp2: bf_stats47_validate_roi_boundary:1739 error: invalid h 92 for x 1306 y 514 w 91 Changed h 91
10-02 16:08:50.673   616 11781 E mm-camera-isp2: bf_stats47_validate_roi_boundary:1732 error: invalid w 92 for x 934 y 608 h 92 Changed w 91
10-02 16:08:50.673   616 11781 E mm-camera-isp2: bf_stats47_validate_roi_boundary:1739 error: invalid h 92 for x 934 y 608 w 91 Changed h 91
10-02 16:08:50.673   616 11781 E mm-camera-isp2: bf_stats47_validate_roi_boundary:1711 error: invalid x 1027 for y 608 w 92 h 92 Changed x 1026
10-02 16:08:50.673   616 11781 E mm-camera-isp2: bf_stats47_validate_roi_boundary:1732 error: invalid w 92 for x 1026 y 608 h 92 Changed w 91
10-02 16:08:50.673   616 11781 E mm-camera-isp2: bf_stats47_validate_roi_boundary:1739 error: invalid h 92 for x 1026 y 608 w 91 Changed h 91
10-02 16:08:50.673   616 11781 E mm-camera-isp2: bf_stats47_validate_roi_boundary:1732 error: invalid w 92 for x 1120 y 608 h 92 Changed w 91
10-02 16:08:50.673   616 11781 E mm-camera-isp2: bf_stats47_validate_roi_boundary:1739 error: invalid h 92 for x 1120 y 608 w 91 Changed h 91
10-02 16:08:50.673   616 11781 E mm-camera-isp2: bf_stats47_validate_roi_boundary:1711 error: invalid x 1213 for y 608 w 92 h 92 Changed x 1212
10-02 16:08:50.673   616 11781 E mm-camera-isp2: bf_stats47_validate_roi_boundary:1732 error: invalid w 92 for x 1212 y 608 h 92 Changed w 91
10-02 16:08:50.673   616 11781 E mm-camera-isp2: bf_stats47_validate_roi_boundary:1739 error: invalid h 92 for x 1212 y 608 w 91 Changed h 91
10-02 16:08:50.674   616 11781 E mm-camera-isp2: bf_stats47_validate_roi_boundary:1732 error: invalid w 92 for x 1306 y 608 h 92 Changed w 91
10-02 16:08:50.674   616 11781 E mm-camera-isp2: bf_stats47_validate_roi_boundary:1739 error: invalid h 92 for x 1306 y 608 w 91 Changed h 91
10-02 16:08:50.674   616 11781 E mm-camera-isp2: bf_stats47_validate_roi_boundary:1725 error: invalid y 701 for x 934 w 92 h 92 Changed y 700
10-02 16:08:50.674   616 11781 E mm-camera-isp2: bf_stats47_validate_roi_boundary:1732 error: invalid w 92 for x 934 y 700 h 92 Changed w 91
10-02 16:08:50.674   616 11781 E mm-camera-isp2: bf_stats47_validate_roi_boundary:1739 error: invalid h 92 for x 934 y 700 w 91 Changed h 91
10-02 16:08:50.674   616 11781 E mm-camera-isp2: bf_stats47_validate_roi_boundary:1711 error: invalid x 1027 for y 701 w 92 h 92 Changed x 1026
10-02 16:08:50.674   616 11781 E mm-camera-isp2: bf_stats47_validate_roi_boundary:1725 error: invalid y 701 for x 1026 w 92 h 92 Changed y 700
10-02 16:08:50.674   616 11781 E mm-camera-isp2: bf_stats47_validate_roi_boundary:1732 error: invalid w 92 for x 1026 y 700 h 92 Changed w 91
10-02 16:08:50.674   616 11781 E mm-camera-isp2: bf_stats47_validate_roi_boundary:1739 error: invalid h 92 for x 1026 y 700 w 91 Changed h 91
10-02 16:08:50.674   616 11781 E mm-camera-isp2: bf_stats47_validate_roi_boundary:1725 error: invalid y 701 for x 1120 w 92 h 92 Changed y 700
10-02 16:08:50.674   616 11781 E mm-camera-isp2: bf_stats47_validate_roi_boundary:1732 error: invalid w 92 for x 1120 y 700 h 92 Changed w 91
10-02 16:08:50.674   616 11781 E mm-camera-isp2: bf_stats47_validate_roi_boundary:1739 error: invalid h 92 for x 1120 y 700 w 91 Changed h 91
10-02 16:08:50.674   616 11781 E mm-camera-isp2: bf_stats47_validate_roi_boundary:1711 error: invalid x 1213 for y 701 w 92 h 92 Changed x 1212
10-02 16:08:50.674   616 11781 E mm-camera-isp2: bf_stats47_validate_roi_boundary:1725 error: invalid y 701 for x 1212 w 92 h 92 Changed y 700
10-02 16:08:50.674   616 11781 E mm-camera-isp2: bf_stats47_validate_roi_boundary:1732 error: invalid w 92 for x 1212 y 700 h 92 Changed w 91
10-02 16:08:50.674   616 11781 E mm-camera-isp2: bf_stats47_validate_roi_boundary:1739 error: invalid h 92 for x 1212 y 700 w 91 Changed h 91
10-02 16:08:50.674   616 11781 E mm-camera-isp2: bf_stats47_validate_roi_boundary:1725 error: invalid y 701 for x 1306 w 92 h 92 Changed y 700
10-02 16:08:50.674   616 11781 E mm-camera-isp2: bf_stats47_validate_roi_boundary:1732 error: invalid w 92 for x 1306 y 700 h 92 Changed w 91
10-02 16:08:50.674   616 11781 E mm-camera-isp2: bf_stats47_validate_roi_boundary:1739 error: invalid h 92 for x 1306 y 700 w 91 Changed h 91
10-02 16:08:50.674   616 11781 E mm-camera-isp2: bf_stats47_validate_roi_boundary:1732 error: invalid w 92 for x 934 y 794 h 92 Changed w 91
10-02 16:08:50.674   616 11781 E mm-camera-isp2: bf_stats47_validate_roi_boundary:1739 error: invalid h 92 for x 934 y 794 w 91 Changed h 91
10-02 16:08:50.674   616 11781 E mm-camera-isp2: bf_stats47_validate_roi_boundary:1711 error: invalid x 1027 for y 794 w 92 h 92 Changed x 1026
10-02 16:08:50.674   616 11781 E mm-camera-isp2: bf_stats47_validate_roi_boundary:1732 error: invalid w 92 for x 1026 y 794 h 92 Changed w 91
10-02 16:08:50.674   616 11781 E mm-camera-isp2: bf_stats47_validate_roi_boundary:1739 error: invalid h 92 for x 1026 y 794 w 91 Changed h 91
10-02 16:08:50.674   616 11781 E mm-camera-isp2: bf_stats47_validate_roi_boundary:1732 error: invalid w 92 for x 1120 y 794 h 92 Changed w 91
10-02 16:08:50.674   616 11781 E mm-camera-isp2: bf_stats47_validate_roi_boundary:1739 error: invalid h 92 for x 1120 y 794 w 91 Changed h 91
10-02 16:08:50.674   616 11781 E mm-camera-isp2: bf_stats47_validate_roi_boundary:1711 error: invalid x 1213 for y 794 w 92 h 92 Changed x 1212
10-02 16:08:50.674   616 11781 E mm-camera-isp2: bf_stats47_validate_roi_boundary:1732 error: invalid w 92 for x 1212 y 794 h 92 Changed w 91
10-02 16:08:50.674   616 11781 E mm-camera-isp2: bf_stats47_validate_roi_boundary:1739 error: invalid h 92 for x 1212 y 794 w 91 Changed h 91
10-02 16:08:50.674   616 11781 E mm-camera-isp2: bf_stats47_validate_roi_boundary:1732 error: invalid w 92 for x 1306 y 794 h 92 Changed w 91
10-02 16:08:50.674   616 11781 E mm-camera-isp2: bf_stats47_validate_roi_boundary:1739 error: invalid h 92 for x 1306 y 794 w 91 Changed h 91
10-02 16:08:50.674   616 11781 E mm-camera-isp2: bf_stats47_sort_ending_pixel_order:2138 i_start = 1199393
10-02 16:08:50.674   616 11781 E mm-camera-isp2: bf_stats47_sort_ending_pixel_order:2138 i_start = 1199485
10-02 16:08:50.674   616 11781 E mm-camera-isp2: be_stats44_trigger_update:447 failed Denomitor is zero hnum 0 vnum 0
10-02 16:08:50.675   616 11781 E mm-camera-isp2: bg_stats44_trigger_update:404 bg_rgn_width 36 bg_rgn_height 27
10-02 16:08:50.675   616 11781 E mm-camera-isp2: abf40_trigger_update:587 aec_ratio.ratio = 0.000000
```

MIUI users, you can also test my application in [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=gmikhail.colorpicker) (please do not leave negative reviews) or create your own new project to check at what stage the error occurs. The project should:

- Use android.hardware.Camera (I know that it's deprecated, but I want to support users on android 4).
- Use TextureView for output (I take a bitmap for color determination in onSurfaceTextureUpdated method.)

I have no idea why this happens. I hope you will help me to identify the cause of the bug.

Answer (score 1):

Just tested your app on my Xiaomi MI4 (LTE) running MIUI 9 Global 7.9.22 | Beta (corresponding Android version : 6.0.1 MMB29M). App runs fine, no blink/incorrect image, and log doesn't spit out any relevant error
Here's a snippet of what logcat looks like :

```
10-04 14:31:19.889 344-17006/? D/QCameraParameters: update current cct value. old:2432, now:2452
10-04 14:31:19.940 377-17034/? E/mm-camera-sensor: port_sensor_handle_aec_update:807 g 15.433594 lux idx 367.901733
10-04 14:31:19.968 377-17034/? E/mm-camera-sensor: port_sensor_handle_aec_update:807 g 14.546875 lux idx 368.742950
10-04 14:31:19.969 344-17006/? D/QCameraParameters: update current cct value. old:2452, now:2462
10-04 14:31:20.008 344-17006/? D/QCameraParameters: update current cct value. old:2462, now:2473
10-04 14:31:20.008 377-17034/? E/mm-camera-sensor: port_sensor_handle_aec_update:807 g 14.546875 lux idx 370.292084
10-04 14:31:20.050 377-17034/? E/mm-camera-sensor: port_sensor_handle_aec_update:807 g 14.546875 lux idx 371.721436
10-04 14:31:20.051 344-17006/? D/QCameraParameters: update current cct value. old:2473, now:2483
10-04 14:31:20.107 377-17034/? E/mm-camera-sensor: port_sensor_handle_aec_update:807 g 14.984375 lux idx 373.024628
10-04 14:31:20.128 377-17034/? E/mm-camera-sensor: port_sensor_handle_aec_update:807 g 15.433594 lux idx 374.805603
10-04 14:31:20.131 373-416/? E/QCALOG: [MessageQ] ProcessNewMessage: [XT-CS] unknown deliver target [OS-Agent]
10-04 14:31:20.173 377-17034/? E/mm-camera-sensor: port_sensor_handle_aec_update:807 g 15.898438 lux idx 375.732544
10-04 14:31:20.184 373-416/? E/QCALOG: [MessageQ] ProcessNewMessage: [XTWiFi-PE] unknown deliver target [OS-Agent]
10-04 14:31:20.189 424-614/? W/XTCC-5.1.0.8: [CS-RIL-LISTENER] timerCallback fired for ril update registering, re-register
10-04 14:31:20.190 373-416/? E/QCALOG: [MessageQ] ProcessNewMessage: [XT-CS] unknown deliver target [OS-Agent]
10-04 14:31:20.208 377-17034/? E/mm-camera-sensor: port_sensor_handle_aec_update:807 g 16.375000 lux idx 375.805603
10-04 14:31:20.209 344-17006/? D/QCameraParameters: update current cct value. old:2483, now:2503
10-04 14:31:20.257 377-17034/? E/mm-camera-sensor: port_sensor_handle_aec_update:807 g 16.867188 lux idx 375.903381
10-04 14:31:20.290 377-17034/? E/mm-camera-sensor: port_sensor_handle_aec_update:807 g 16.867188 lux idx 375.168091
10-04 14:31:20.291 344-17006/? D/QCameraParameters: update current cct value. old:2503, now:2513
10-04 14:31:20.335 377-17034/? E/mm-camera-sensor: port_sensor_handle_aec_update:807 g 16.867188 lux idx 375.332733
10-04 14:31:20.371 377-17034/? E/mm-camera-sensor: port_sensor_handle_aec_update:807 g 17.375000 lux idx 376.332733
10-04 14:31:20.372 344-17006/? D/QCameraParameters: update current cct value. old:2513, now:2524
10-04 14:31:20.408 377-17034/? E/mm-camera-sensor: port_sensor_handle_aec_update:807 g 17.375000 lux idx 377.168091
10-04 14:31:20.451 377-17034/? E/mm-camera-sensor: port_sensor_handle_aec_update:807 g 17.894531 lux idx 378.024628
10-04 14:31:20.453 386-460/? I/ThermalEngine: Sensor:batt_temp:354 mC
10-04 14:31:20.511 377-17034/? E/mm-camera-sensor: port_sensor_handle_aec_update:807 g 17.894531 lux idx 377.332733
10-04 14:31:20.531 377-17034/? E/mm-camera-sensor: port_sensor_handle_aec_update:807 g 17.894531 lux idx 376.517487
10-04 14:31:20.531 344-17006/? D/QCameraParameters: update current cct value. old:2524, now:2534
10-04 14:31:20.570 377-17034/? E/mm-camera-sensor: port_sensor_handle_aec_update:807 g 17.894531 lux idx 376.721436
10-04 14:31:20.609 377-17034/? E/mm-camera-sensor: port_sensor_handle_aec_update:807 g 17.894531 lux idx 375.943665
10-04 14:31:20.609 344-17006/? D/QCameraParameters: update current cct value. old:2534, now:2544
10-04 14:31:20.651 377-17034/? E/mm-camera-sensor: port_sensor_handle_aec_update:807 g 17.894531 lux idx 376.721436
10-04 14:31:20.932 344-17006/? D/QCameraParameters: update current cct value. old:2544, now:2564
10-04 14:31:20.940 17727-17727/? D/wpa_supplicant: wlan0: Control interface command 'SIGNAL_POLL'
10-04 14:31:20.943 17727-17727/? D/wpa_supplicant: CTRL-DEBUG: global_ctrl_sock-sendto: sock=11 sndbuf=163840 outq=0 send_len=48
10-04 14:31:21.129 377-17034/? E/mm-camera-sensor: port_sensor_handle_aec_update:807 g 17.894531 lux idx 375.943665
10-04 14:31:21.129 344-17006/? D/QCameraParameters: update current cct value. old:2564, now:2575
10-04 14:31:21.329 377-17034/? E/mm-camera-sensor: port_sensor_handle_aec_update:807 g 17.894531 lux idx 376.721436
10-04 14:31:21.455 386-460/? I/ThermalEngine: Sensor:batt_temp:355 mC
10-04 14:31:21.494 344-17006/? D/QCameraParameters: update current cct value. old:2575, now:2585
10-04 14:31:22.015 344-17006/? D/QCameraParameters: update current cct value. old:2585, now:2595
10-04 14:31:22.456 386-460/? I/ThermalEngine: Sensor:batt_temp:355 mC
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I can assume that the problem was fixed in new versions of MIUI.